typescript variable with explicit type annotation being incorrectly narrowed
Say I have a mutable variable with an explicit type annotation that's a union (e.g. let val: number | null = null;). I want it to remain that union type, but it is immediately narrowed to null.
If I set it to a number, it will then be inferred as type number. That is, unless I set it to a number in a function that is called synchronously; after that it's still a type null.
Here is a minimal example of code, which reproduces the issue when pasted into the typescript playground with default settings and (current) version v5.7.2:
let val: number | null = null;
const val2 = val; // <-- inferred to be `const val2: null`

const setValToNumber = () => {
    val = 0;
};
setValToNumber();

const val3 = val; // <-- this is definitely a number now, but type is still `null`
console.log(val, val2, val3); // <-- logs `0, null, 0`

I had thought that since I explicitly annotated the var, it would "transfer" that full type to any other variables set to it. I caught this when similar code to my example was in a function, returning val, but the return type was not inferred to number | null as I expected, but merely null.
const getVal = () => {
  // insert sample code above
  return val;
}
const val = getVal(); // <-- this val is type `null`

I can explicitly annotate the function with (): number | null to get around this, but the narrowing inference was unexpected, and frankly in this case, incorrect. Could one consider this a bug in the compiler?

Assignment narrowing is an intentional feature of TypeScript, not a bug. The issue with functions mutating closed-over variables is essentially a design limitation of TS, as described in painstaking detail in ms/TS#9998. TS cannot possibly track these kinds of mutations, so it makes simplifying assumptions, which necessarily gets things wrong sometimes.  Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

Thanks for the link to the github issue. It definitely describes what I'm seeing. I couldn't find anything on this gotcha/limitation in the handbook (I might be blind), and I thought I remembered in the past that an explicit annotation is kept (the handbook examples all start with an inferred type, not explicit annotations). I didn't mean to suggest that assignment narrowing overall is a bug, but that the incorrect analysis felt bug-like, where I'd expect the compiler to notice a possibility of side effect and "unnarrow". (continued...)

TS's handbook unfortunately doesn't contain everything one might want to know about TS, and TS doesn't have a formal language spec. They've said that the language changes too much to keep a spec up to date, so the GitHub issues are part of their documentation. If you want to know something about how TS works, you might need to search GitHub issues for relevant keywords. So, does this fully address the q? Shall I write an answer or find a duplicate? I'm not missing anything about the question, right?

(...cont) What's odd is that it never narrows if I use let val: number | null = null as number | null;. I always thought the as x was looser than the : x annotation, and I tend to avoid as like the plague. Was it different in the past? Or maybe compiler settings affect assignment narrowing in some way? I guess if you can include some details on this plus the link etc. I'd be glad to approve the answer.

This behavior has been this way for as long as I've been using TS.  The assertion is on the value, so null as number | null is seen as type number | null, and when you assign it to val there is no narrowing.  But just null has type null, so when you assign it to val there is narrowing.  Assertions and annotations happen in syntactically different places. Yes, assertions are "looser" in that they let you unsafely narrow instead of safely widen. Using as to widen is safe (but if you're worried about safety, satisfies X as X is always safe, if redundant).
